# USB network adapter needs to be re-plugged every day

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb, wireshark

I have a Digitus USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet adapter which I use for monitoring network traffic of our device in the test lab. As such, it's connected to the mirroring port of my HP-1820-8G switch.

Part of my job is to run Wireshark and capture the traffic, so I start Wireshark every day - and every day I need to re-plug that adapter in order to make it work. Otherwise it's not detected by Windows (not visible in the device manager)

What can I do to have the USB 3.0 network adapter available without re-plugging it?

Details:

- the Digitus USB 3.0 adapter is recognized as ASIX AX88179 by Windows
- I use Windows 7 SP1 x64
- I have a Fujitsu Lifebook E series laptop that is placed in a docking station
- the USB network adapter is connected to a USB 3.0 port of the docking station
- Driver is ASIX 1.14.8.0 from 2013-12-03
- Hardware IDs: VID 0B95, PID 1790 REV 0100
- The built-in Windows driver update does not find a newer driver
- I'm shutting down the PC every day in the evening and power it up in the morning. I do not use Standby or Hibernate

I have tried:

- Updating the driver from the [ASIX homepage](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112), now using the latest Windows 7 64-bit Driver version 1.14.11.0 from 2016-04-06

Comment: is the device no longer detected by windows or otherwise? "not working" is pretty imprecise.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but have you tried looking at your laptops power-plan? Maybe it turns off the usb to save power? I've had that happen to me before..

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: it's not detected by Windows, i.e. not visible in device manager. Updated the question

Comment: @Bungicasse: I'm shutting down every day, neither standby nor hibernate. Updated the question.

Comment: If it's not powering up with the machine it can't be the power plan. Kinda tempted to suggest a hub with a physical switch for the port